# CDN for Angular 2 release candidate

Tags: angular

I found a CDN for Angular 2 before RC, but not after release candidate 1 .

Is there a CDN for Angular 2 release candidate 3?

Comment: I guess this contains what you need https://plnkr.co/edit/tpl:AvJOMERrnz94ekVua0u5

Comment: Looks like Google is not hosting angular 2 yet https://developers.google.com/speed/libraries/

Comment: @Günter the plunker works. I just dont know how: in config.js a url https://npmcdn.com/@angular is configured. I cant access the url and also when looking at the network traffic there is no request for an angular file.

Comment: It's the `system.js` script and `System.import('app')` from `index.html` that make it work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After beta, RC is not yet pused to `CDN`. But I guess it has already been pused to `NPM`.

Here, this is `RC.3` working example if you want to go ahead with a plunkr.

https://plnkr.co/edit/y0lzI4S5w83Vliv6yOo0?p=preview.